# Giving HTTP 500 error, Windows Laravel 5.7

Tags: php, windows, laravel, virtualhost, http-status-code-500

Using `php artisan serve` and the virtual host of `Wamp64` both give `HTML Error`.
If I use the laravel in the `www` folder of `Wamp64` it works. However, I'd like to use a Virtual Host of my Project that I can have in `c:/Projects/myProject`.
My Laravel Project is the default after the `laravel new blog` command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember you need a server(Apache/Nginx)to run php webpages, so i would suggest you move your Projects folder to your Wamp ROOT folder(www in your case), then run your php artisan serve command from within the laravel project folder.

Comment: There is no other way to use Laravel in a  VHost on Windows?

Comment: Heres how i configured my vhost, im also a windows machine... i commented out the defaults, and added this: <VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs"
    ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/Portfolio/public"
    ServerName Portfolio.test
</VirtualHost>